# Video on Scroll Animation really choppy on server

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm currently working on a Video on Scroll animation. It works really well in local device but when I upload it on the server it gets lagged too much. I tried compressing the video but nothing is changing. The video I'm trying to put in is a 1 minute 54 second video.

```
const intro = document.querySelector(".intro");
const video = intro.querySelector("video");
const text = intro.querySelector("h1");
//END SECTION
const section = document.querySelector("section");
const end = section.querySelector("h1");

//SCROLLMAGIC
const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

//Scenes
let scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  duration: 113000,
  triggerElement: intro,
  triggerHook: 0
})
  
  .setPin(intro)
  .addTo(controller);

//Text Animation
const textAnim = TweenMax.fromTo(text, 3, { opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 0 });

let scene2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  duration: 0,
  triggerElement: intro,
  triggerHook: 0
})
  .setTween(textAnim)
  .addTo(controller);

//Video Animation
let accelamount = 0.1;
let scrollpos = 0;
let delay = 0;

scene.on("update", e => {
  scrollpos = e.scrollPos / 1000;
});

setInterval(() => {
  delay += (scrollpos - delay) * accelamount;
  console.log(scrollpos, delay);

  video.currentTime = delay;
}, 33.3);
```

Comment: You say you uploaded a video and you have some CSS here.. Maybe your download speed is causing the video play back choppyness (buffering) and not an actual problem with anything you did? If it works locally the only difference between local and remote... is network speed.

Comment: GreenSock doesn't recommend ScrollMagic. Instead they recommend the official scroll plugin: [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/)! It's better in every way.